# Is information conserved in an expanding universe?

Tags: cosmology, quantum-information, conservation-laws, space-expansion, information

From the classical and quantum mechanical viewpoint, is information conserved in an expanding universe or not?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29175/50583 for a general discussion of "conservation of information"