# Is the indestructibility of information a tautology?

Tags: information

What I was thinking was that, if we imagined a piece of information being destroyed, lost forever, wouldn't that require that there be no evidence that the information had ever existed since that information would have effected various states of particles and fields that would have been affected by the creation and existence of that information.  It almost seems to me that for information to be lost, then it would have never existed in the first place because everything that would have been in a different state had the information existed would have to be put back where it would have been had the information never existed.

So is the indestructibility of information just a tautology since the evidence of the "prior" existence of a piece of information would contain that information?

Comment: How are you defining "information"? Questions like this depend extremely sensitively upon on the specific definition you're using, as there are likely some definitions that make this tautological and definitions for which it isn't.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29175/109928

Comment: No, you can imagine scenarios in which information is indeed destroyed. And created too.